# (Unity C#) How do I find the number of strings with a specific value?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

Basically, I have 4 strings in my project. I would like to know how many of these 4 have the specific value I'm looking for.

For example, the values of the 4 strings are "stack" "stack" "overflow" "problem". I want to be able to get a value of 2 for stack, 1 for overflow, and 1 for problem.

Comment: pretty small amount of amount, just use Contain() inside a where query with count

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is using a LINQ operator. In this case, .Where(s => condition) will return a list of all instances that match a condition. This uses the .Count() of the result.

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
  "stack", "stack", "overflow", "problem"
};

IEnumerable<string> foundStrings = strings.Where(s => s == "stack");
Debug.WriteLine(foundStrings.Count());
```

Comment: You can make it shorter by directly going through the `Count` like `Debug.WriteLine(foundStrings.Count(s => s == "stack"));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...


List<string> strings = new List<string>()
{
    "stack", "stack", "problem", "overflow", "stack", "problem"
};


var itemCounts = strings
    // first builds groups by according item
    .GroupBy(s => s)
    // converts the collection of various groups to a collection of KeyValuePairs mapping item -> count
    .Select(g => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Count()));

// optionally sort by the count (most frequent first) and print them
foreach (var keyValuePair in itemCounts.OrderByDescending(g => g.Value))
{
    Debug.Log($"{keyValuePair.Key} : {keyValuePair.Value}");

    // ... or do something else ;)
}
```

Output:

```
stack : 3
problem : 2
overflow : 1
```

See

- [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2XOA1F)
- [Linq `GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby)
- [Linq `ToDictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary)
- [Linq `OrderByDescending`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending)